# list all files with a paticular extension of a dir in C

Tags: c, file, function, unix

In C, can I list all files with certain extension inside a dir?

Any api available?

"ls" would be the last thing I want to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On UNIX, you're looking for `opendir` and `readdir` (and maybe `fnmatch`) or alternatively `glob` (which puts those three together for you). These are not part of C, but rather POSIX.

Comment: Awesome! this is exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate your quickness :)

Comment: I also interested in file creation times for those files. Does anyone provide that?

Comment: @hari: UNIX does not store creation time. You can get the times that UNIX does store (modify, access, status change) by calling `stat`.